# Parse info from views to html and generate pdf

Tags: python, django, pdf

I'm using the django environment and creating PDF's with the library PDFkit. The pdfkit accept's 3 methods :

```
pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf')
pdfkit.from_file('test.html', 'out.pdf')
pdfkit.from_string('Hello!', 'out.pdf')
```

But I don't know how to redirect from url with information(dict) like (that's not correct ) :

```
 pdfkit.from_url(render(request,'reports/test.html',dicto), 'out.pdf',options=options)
```

How can I parse an object Httpresponse to this method? ( or another one ? )

Thx a lot.

Comment: You want to open pdf file in Httpresponse ?

Comment: I want to parse the HTML with info from python var's. Maybe I don't need to parse a url, can I convert this HttpResponse to a string and use pdfkit.from_string() ?

Comment: ok the solution is render_to_string, sorry and thx